# Overlapping Items in CheckedListBox

Tags: winforms, checkedlistbox

Has any one seen this behavior before? At design-time the values look correct, at run-time they appear as they do the screen shot.

It's a simple CheckedListBox with items populated via the items collection at design time.

I've created a brand new project in the same solution and the issue is not present. A new form in the same project displays the same behavior. So it's not monitor or display related.

[image: Example]

Comment: Does it have this behaviour if you make a new project with just a CheckedListBox? If your 4k monitor is indeed the problem I wouldn't be able to test it.

Comment: I just made a new project and can't reproduce, when I set the font size bigger it just adjusts the item size.

Comment: I've created a brand new project in the same solution and the issue is not present. A new form in the same project displays the same behavior. So it's not monitor related.  I will update the question.

Comment: Ah so its project related.. Maybe someone has had the same but otherwise they will not be able to figure out why without the project specifics.

Comment: This can happen when you set the form's AutoScaleMode property to Dpi instead of Font, the monitor operates at a setting higher than 100% (common on Win10) and you declared the app to be dpiAware.  You need Font to ensure that text fits correctly after rescaling.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it is already set to Font.